# HTML doesn't load files from <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load several Javascript files in the head of my HTML, but as soon as I want to use the function inside them, it says

> ReferenceError: enter is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

It works when I try to run it locally, but as soon as I test it on the server it doesn't work anymore. Here's some code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./graphics/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/lightbox.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" id="enterDE" onclick="enter()">
        <img src="./graphics/flag.jpg" alt="flag" style="height: 80px; margin-right: 40px">
    </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The only thing it actually loads is the CSS.

Help would be appreciated, I'm about to give up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are getting reference errors, you are running some JS. Where are you using `$` and `enterEN`? Inside `main.js`?

Comment: My bad, wanted to clean it up a bit, I edited it now.
I use $ and enter in main.js.

Comment: I would check a couple things to start.  1.  Is your relative path correct for the javascript?  Try loading the javascript path directly in the browser.  2.  Does your web server send back the right content-type headers for the javascript.

Comment: sounds like jquery isnt being loaded. double check the location and spelling of filenames.

Comment: Function invocation needs brackets () , what is "enter" here??

Comment: onclick="enter" should be onclick="enter();"

Comment: What happens when you try to access it? What HTTP status code do you get?

Comment: @sberry

1. The path exists, but I can't access it. Should I be able to as an extern client?

2. Response-Type is text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: *"Should I be able to as an extern client"* yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<a href="#" id="enterDE" onclick="enter();">
```

Instead of

```
<a href="#" id="enterDE" onclick="enter()">
```

---

Also, is your `src` property from the `script` element alright to link your files?